# How do i stream an audio file from the server to iphone?

Tags: iphone, audio, streaming

I need to stream an audio file which is saved on my server. Is it possible for me to stream that file in order to play it on my iPhone? Or is there any other way to play an audio file from the server to iPhone? help me please.

Thanks,

Shibin

Comment: There are apps that do this, what have you tried?  Are you looking to write an app to do this?  What has your research turned up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link was useful to me : http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

He's got a project linked from that page http://projectswithlove.com/projects/iPhoneStreamingPlayer.zip

In this project, interesting lines are in iPhoneStreamingPlayerViewController.m, lines 82-89 start streaming the audio from a url.

I've manged to get this running on my iPhone and tested it using an mp3 on another server and it works fine. However, I've not picked through the code so I can't help you anymore than this, sorry!

Sam

NS To get the project to compile I had to change the SDK to 3.0 - if you right click on the project name and choose Get Info, then change the option called Base SDK to iPhone Device 3.0 and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to get the file playing on the iPhone, but the first problem is that you need to decide how to serve the file from your server.

One great way is to share the file out via HTTP using a Web Server. If the server is Windows, look into 'IIS'. If it's a Mac or Linux, Apache is your friend.

Once you've got the serving going, here are the options on the iPhone:

1) Use iPhone Safari to navigate to http://your-server/your-folder/the-file.ext. If the serving is correct, it'll open the mediaplayer and stream it.

2) Write an iPhone application that uses the AVMediaPlayer framework to play the file. Non-trivial, but there are plenty of samples.